Go Types for BNF Grammar
I'm working on the crafting interpreters book and as a personal project I've decided to implement JLox on Go instead of Java mainly to learn Go.
Currently I'm stuck with the parser, I'm unsure how to use the type system to build on the grammar. There are some clues here but I want to use types a la Haskell or Rust (maybe I'm mistaken here) .
So far this is what I've got:
package ast

import (
    "golox/lexer"
)

type Stream interface {
    Peek() lexer.Token
    Next() lexer.Token
}
type TokenStream []lexer.Token

func (s *TokenStream) Peek() lexer.Token {
    return (*s)[0]
}

func (s *TokenStream) Next() lexer.Token {
    result := (*s)[0]
    *s = (*s)[1:]
    return result
}

type NUMBER struct {value float32}
type STRING struct {value string}
type NULL struct {value any}
type BOOL struct {value bool}

func (v NUMBER) Value() float32 {
    return v.value
}

func (v STRING) Value() string {
    return v.value
}

func (v BOOL) Value() bool {
    return v.value
}

func (v NULL) Value() {
}

type Literal interface {
    NUMBER | STRING | BOOL | NULL
}

type Expr interface {Literal | Unary | Binary | Grouping}

type Grouping[E Expr] struct {
    right lexer.Token
    left lexer.Token
    expr *E
}

type Unary[E Expr] struct {
    operator lexer.Token
    expr *E
}

type Binary[E Expr] struct {
    operator lexer.Token
    left *E
    right *E
}

func ParseType(s Stream) (err error) {
    switch p:=s.Peek(); p {

    }

    return
}


My intent is to type check on the token stream and then join those tokens as expressions of different kinds. My main question lies on the types I've defined since the compiler complains that my definitions are invalid (I thought that providing a pointer as a field for the recursive type would suffice, but alas it doesn't).
Any insight is appreciated!
I know there probably is an implementation of this language in go but I would like to understand this problem before checking someone else's answer!

"the compiler complains that my definitions are invalid" You should post the exact error message and make sure we can identify which line(s) in the posted code trigger the(se) error(s). Please note that type constraints in Go's generics do not provide a means to model what is know as sum types.

You are trying to build an AST. Take a look at how it is done for Go here https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast@go1.23.0

The compilation error is invalid recursive type Expr, and it is because you declare Expr as set of types, the type may be one of (Literal | Unary | Binary | Grouping) union. The compiler tries to resolve E at compile time based on the type constraint Expr, and because Expr contains Grouping, which creates a recursive type reference, leading to the error.

I thought that providing a pointer as a field for the recursive type would suffice, but alas it doesn't

You may wondering why it works
type A struct {
    a *A
}

this is because The compiler knows exactly what *A is (pointer to A) if no generics involved whereas recursive type constraints are invalid even if you use pointer
In other language like Rust, we can define an enum type to describe all the possible expressions:
#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Literal {
    Bool(bool),
    Number(String),
    String(String),
    Null,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Expression {
    Litera(Literal),
    Grouping(Box<Expression>),
    Unary(Token, Box<Expression>),
    Binary(Box<Expression>, Token, Box<Expression>),
}

But since golang do not have enum type, the idiomatic way to implement it is using interface
var (
    _ Expr = new(Literal)
    _ Expr = new(Grouping)
    _ Expr = new(Unary)
    _ Expr = new(Binary)
)

type Expr interface {
    Evaluate() string
}

type Literal struct {
    Value string
}

func (l *Literal) Evaluate() string {
    return l.Value
}

type Grouping struct {
    Expr Expr
}

func (g *Grouping) Evaluate() string {
    if g.Expr == nil {
        return ""
    } else {
        return fmt.Sprintf("(group %s)", g.Expr.Evaluate())
    }
}

type Unary struct {
    Token *Token
    Right Expr
}

func (u *Unary) Evaluate() string {
    if u.Right == nil {
        return ""
    } else {
        token := ""
        if u.Token != nil {
            token = u.Token.Data
        }
        return fmt.Sprintf("(%s %s)", token, u.Right.Evaluate())
    }
}

type Binary struct {
    Left  Expr
    Token *Token
    Right Expr
}

type A struct {
    a *A
}

func (b *Binary) Evaluate() string {
    if b.Left == nil || b.Right == nil || b.Token == nil {
        return ""
    } else {
        return fmt.Sprintf("(%s %s %s)", b.Token.Data, b.Left.Evaluate(), b.Right.Evaluate())
    }
}

